# Running node server.js throws syntax error

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs

I have my basic server.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('src/client/'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/client/index.html'))
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('server started');
```

however I now have a react-routing that I want to import so that when the browser is refreshed on the server the page is still accessible.

My attempt so far is:

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router';
import routes from './src/client/app/config/routes.jsx';

let port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
let app = express();

app.use(express.static('src/client/'));

// app.get('/', (req, res) from> {
//  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/client/index.html'))
// });

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  match(
    { routes, location: req.url },
    (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {

      // in case of error display the error message
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err.message);
      }

      // in case of redirect propagate the redirect to the browser
      if (redirectLocation) {
        return res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
      }

      // generate the React markup for the current route
      let markup;
      if (renderProps) {
        // if the current route matched we have renderProps
        markup = renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps}/>);
      } 
      // else {
      //   // otherwise we can render a 404 page
      //   markup = renderToString(<NotFoundPage/>);
      //   res.status(404);
      // }

      // render the index template with the embedded React markup
      return res.render(path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/client/index.html'));
    }
  );
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('server started');
```

but when I run "node server.js" I get the following error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import express from 'express';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

Comment: `import` is an ES2015 keyword that NodeJS does not recognize. You will have to use the transpiled version of this file.

Comment: but this "app.get('/', (req, res) => {" (arrow function) was already existing in my previous server.js meaning that ES2015 can be used

Comment: Right, so you'll have to run the transpiled version of this file. Node had early support for fat arrows; you used to have to run with `--harmony` and then at some point I think it was native--don't recall. `import` you'll need to transpile with your version of Node, just like the error indicates.

Comment: node.js does now support ALL the features of ES6 though it does support a lot of them. This is a page that lists what node supports and what it does not: http://node.green/

Answer (score 0):

Just about everything in ES6 works in new versions of node except for the import/export keyword. You'll have to transpile it to ES5 with gulp, webpack, etc.